# #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row - How to handle this in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have one mysql query like this

```
"select n.message, count(n.id),
(select m.id from new2 AS m where m.message = n.message)
from new2 as n
group by n.message"
```

in table new2 I have the combination of id, message

And I need to get the id and count of id's who having same message value..

How to do that ?

structure of my table is

```
       id   message
        1   m1
        2   m2
        3   m3
        4   m1
        5   m2
        6   m2
        7   m1
```

I need to get the output like

```
 message    count(n.id) ids
m1          3           1,4,7
m2          3           2,5,6
m3          1           3
```

Comment: Can u give some dummy data with the structure?

Comment: id    message
   1 m1
   2 m2
   3 m3
   4 m1
   5 m2
   6 m2
   7 m1

Comment: what are you trying to do? are you trying to get the id's of the given message or get how many of those messages are in the table?

Comment: I need to get the output like

     message count(n.id) ids
    m1         3         1,4,7
    m2         3         2,5,6
    m3         1         3

Answer (score 2):

no need subquery, you can use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to get all ids from a group

```
SELECT n.message, COUNT(n.id), GROUP_CONCAT(n.id)
FROM new2 as n
GROUP BY n.message
```

## DEMO

Answer (score 0):

You are getting more than one row in the query.

```
(select m.id from new2 AS m where m.message = n.message)
```

Use `LIMIT` to avoid the error.

```
select n.message, count(n.id),
(select m.id from new2 AS m where m.message = n.message LIMIT 1)
from new2 as n
group by n.message
```

Comment: But I need to display all those id's who having same message value

Answer (score 0):

this will get you a distinct list of messages and a count of how many of each:

```
select n.message, count(n.id) from new2 as n group by n.message
```